# Is it possible to submit more than 1 choices in "set /p choice" in batch programming?

Tags: batch-file

So here is my code, i will try to explain my problem a little better.

```
@echo off
cls
title Sold Products
:start
echo Products
echo.
echo.
echo  1) Product1     2) Product2
echo.
echo  3) Product3     4) Product4
echo.
echo  5) Product5     6) Product6
echo.
set /p products= What products have been sold?: 
echo %products% >> products.txt
goto start
```

basically what i need is.. instead of choosing only 1 product a time, i would like to be able to choose more than one and append them on the txt file... like product1 and product2.

P.S. sry for my bad english....

Comment: no. it's a simple string input. whatever the user types up until they hit return gets stuffed into the specified environment variable. whether that's a zero length string or the contents of War & Peace doesn't matter - it's all just a string. it's up to you to process/use that string afterwards.

Comment: I don't completely agree. You actually CAN do this by parsing the string the user entered. However, parsing strings in batch is quite a pain in the a** so I'd rather pick a different script language. If you REALLY need to do this in batch, tell me and I'll try to help you.

Comment: @MichaelS no its fine, thank you very much for your help and i am glad that you are willing to help me.